# hide input[type=submit] and show loading image not working

Tags: jquery, click, submit

using jquery, i am trying to hide the submit button and show an ajax loading gif once it is clicked.

it is working fine, but the form does not get submitted anymore.

heres my jquery code:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('p').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />');
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
});
```

heres my html:

```
<h1>add</h1>

<form method="post" action="form.php">

<p>
<label for="number">number:</label>
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" size="30" value="" />
</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
<input type="submit" value="add" />
</p>

</form>
```

as you can see, i even added `$(this).parent('form').submit();` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('p:last-child', this).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />');
});
```

Comment: i ended up using the submit function and did some different things. the problem with the solution you provided is the ajax-loader.gif does not animate when this method is used, so i had to add the image inside the P with the submit and hide() the submit and show() the image.